# code is returning an net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when trying to login. When true should open LoggedIn.html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, body-parser

code is returning a `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` when trying to login. I have the username and password hardcoded.

All that I want is when the admin inputs the username and password on the `Employee.html` page if it is equal to the username and password on the `main.js` file When then open `LoggedIn.html` page.

however, I am getting `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

**From my main.js file**

```
app.post('/admin', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var passw    = req.body.passw;
    console.log(username + ' - ' + passw);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    if (username === 'Admin' && passw === 'Password1') 
    {
        res.send('LoggidIn.html');
    }
    else
    {
        res.send('');
    }
});
```

**From my admin.js file**

```
var myconn = new XMLHttpRequest();

myconn.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) 
    {
        window.location.href = myconn.responseText;
    };
};

function AdminFunction() 
{
    username_   =  document.getElementById("id_username").value;
    password_   =  document.getElementById("id_password").value;

    /* Validate !!! the data before posting it to the SERVER [BEST PRACTICE TO DO THIS SERVER SIDE ASWELL] */
    /*------------------------------------------------------ */
    if (username_ === "") {alert("Username is empty"); return false;}
    if (password_ === "") {alert("Password is empty"); return false;}
    /*------------------------------------------------------ */

    data = {username:username_, passw:password_};
    myconn.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/admin", true);
    myconn.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    myconn.send(JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

**From my EmployeeLogon.html page**

```
<form name="The_Form" class="form1" onsubmit="return AdminFunction()">
    <input class="un " type="text" id="id_username" placeholder="Username">
    <input class="pass" type="password"  id="id_password" placeholder="Password">
    <input class="submit" type="submit"  value="Sign in">
    <p class="forgot"><a href="Error404.html">Forgot Password?</a></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you verify...In console that you are entering 
Username : Admin and  password: Password1...
For debugging you can put your response in variable 
Before sending that variable print it in console.

Comment: the console outputs Admin-Password1 when you enter the credentials

Comment: Sorry To check this so...Late...Was it the spelling mistake?  You wrote res.send('LoggidIn.html') instead of res.send('LoggedIn.html')